# Grep the first (2 digit) number after a \+ sign

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, grep

TL:DR I'd like the syntax for the first two numbers on any line that immediately follow a '+' sign.

Given the following text (from a familiar utility):

```
power_meter-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
power1:        4.29 MW (interval = 4294967.29 s)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +38.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 2:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 3:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 4:         +37.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 5:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 1:  +43.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +38.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 2:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 3:         +37.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 4:         +36.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 5:         +37.0°C  (high = +75.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

I need to get the interesting numbers out, i.e. 44, 36, 38, 36, 36, 37, etc...

From the command line in Linux, I used `sensors | awk '{ print $3 }' | egrep -o '\+..' | sed 's/^.//'` which outputs 12 of the 14 interesting numbers and is not that elegant.

Comment: `sensors | sed -r 's/^.*\+([[:digit:]]+)\.[[:digit:]].C .*/\1/'`

Comment: @EdMorton It's "Too long, didn't read" - providing a summary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, in an awk one-liner:

```
sensors | awk -F'[+.]' '/\+/{print $2}'
```

That assumes numbers start with '+'.  If temperature might start with a minus, you might want to add:

```
sensors | awk -F'[-+.]' '/high/{print $2}'
```

Really, depends on what you're certain you can key off of.

And, of course, if the temperatures really start with a minus, you probably have bigger problems.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed and grep combined:

```
$ sensors | sed 's/^[^+]*+\([0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1/g' | grep -o "^[0-9][0-9]$" 
44
36
38
36
36
37
36
43
36
38
36
37
36
37
```

The `sed` command maps each line to the it's first pair of digits. The `grep` command filters out each line that isn't two digits.

Comment: if you remove `/g` from `sed` you don't need `grep`, since you are no longer doing a global substitution

Comment: Still need the `grep` to filter  out empty lines and header lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n 's/[^+]*+\([0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p' file
44
36
38
36
36
37
36
43
36
38
36
37
36
37
```

Answer (score 1):

A single grep can do it, if we take advantage of the fact that there is an opening parenthesis somewhere behind the first number, but not behind the others:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\+|-)\d+(?=\.\d°C\s+\()' infile
44
36
38
36
36
37
36
43
36
38
36
37
36
37
```

With Perl regex engine (`-P`) and extracting only matches (`-o`):

```
(?<=\+|=)        # Positive look-behind: + or -
\d+              # The digits we're extracting
(?=\.\d°C\s+\()  # Positive look-ahead: dot digit °C spaces and (
```

Comment: I really appreciate when somebody comments their regex - it's an obtuse script.